# Upgrade/backport evolution to latest version

Tags: upgrade, evolution, backport

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, with default applications.
Now I have tested Ubuntu 11.04, but it is not a LTS version, so I want to upgrade evolution of 10.04 to 11.04, because the evolution in 11.04 is far better then evolution in Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [exising Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maverick-backports/+bug/653619) requesting a backport of Evolution v2.32 to 10.04.

The backport is not a simple process:

> Backporting Evolution 2.32 to 10.04 requires backporting at least a
>   dozen other packages - new GLib and Gtk+, few other libraries, e-d-s,
>   modules that evolution uses to provide additional features like
>   Exchange support, and most likely evolution-couchdb. This is far to
>   invasive for an in archive backport. A PPA is the best way to support
>   this.

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kklimonda/+archive/evo232) exists purports to do just this upgrade.

However heed this maintainers warning:

> WARNING: There is no easy way to go back to the 2.28 release once you
>   launch 2.32 - new Evolution migrates data to the new directory
>   structure making them incompatible with the old release.

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kklimonda/evo232 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Have a valid disk-image that you can return to if the PPA makes your system unstable**

Comment: At least backup your evolution folder. `.evolution` maybe.